# Relative homology and path connected space 2

Tags: algebraic-topology

In this post ([Relative homology and path connected space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560457/relative-homology-and-path-connected-space)) it is proved that if $X$ is a path connected space and $Y\subset X$ is not empty, then $H_0(X,Y)\simeq0$. I was wondering if the reciprocal is true; more exactly, suppose for all subset $Y$, $Y\not=\emptyset$,  of a topological space $X$, $H_0(X,Y)\simeq0$ holds. Can we conclude that $X$ is path connected?

Comment: No, we cannot. I suggest you carefully read the answer of the other post you link, as it already answers this question.

Comment: @Thorgott care to elaborate why "no"? By taking $Y$ to be a single point the other answer implies the same thing, that a single point has to meet each path component, and so the space is path connected.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I read "a" instead of "all" for the subsets $Y$ (which would be the actual converse to the statement, unlike what it actually says). I agree then, of course, that, yes, we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H_n(X,x_0)\simeq \widetilde{H_n}(X)$ for any point $x_0\in X$: [Homology relative to a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58980/homology-relative-to-a-point)

And thus $H_0(X,x_0)\simeq 0$ for some (any) point $x_0\in X$ is equivalent to $\widetilde{H_0}(X)\simeq 0$ which is equivalent to $X$ being path connected: [The zeroth homology group corresponds to path components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772999/the-zeroth-homology-group-corresponds-to-path-components)

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is YES contrary to what Thorgott says. Correct?

Comment: @M.Rahmat I think that the answer is YES. We don't need to look at all subsets $Y$, it is enough when $H_0(X,x_0)\simeq 0$ for some point $x_0$. I don't see any issue with my answer. And I don't really understand Thorgott's comment. The answer to the other question actually says the same thing via different method.